# What is wrong with my logic?

Tags: c++

```
if(location[0] <= 'H' || location[0] >= 'A' 
&& location[1] <= 8 || location[1] >= 1)
```

I am checking to see if the first indice is between 'A' and 'H' and the second indice is between 1 - 8.

so the argument would = 1 if the user entered { A, 1 }
-1 if the user entered { J, 1 }

Comment: I guess what i'm really after, is how many arguments can be put inside of a conditional statement?

Comment: For future reference : http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, new here. I should have posted my entire method. Thank you for explaining the precedence of the operators, but my issue was that I was comparing a char with an int. All I needed to do was put ' ' around my numbers.

```
void GameBoard::enterShips()
{
    char location[2];
    int ships = 0;
    int count = 1;

    while( ships < NUM_SHIPS )
    {
        cout << "Enter a location for Ship " << count << ": ";
        cin >> location[0];
        cin >> location[1];
        cout << endl;

        if((location[0] <= 'H' && location[0] >= 'A') && (location[1] <= '8' && location[1] >= '1'))
        {
            location[0] = location[0] - 64;
            location[1]--;
            Grid[location[0]][location[1]] = SHIP;
            ships++;
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Wrong coordinates entered. Try again." << endl << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

And (`&&`) has higher precedence than or (`||`), so to express what you want you need:

```
if ((location[0] <= 'H' || location[0] >= 'A') && (location[1] <= 8 || location[1] >= 1))
```

Otherwise what's happening is that it does the equivalent of this:

```
if (location[0] <= 'H' || (location[0] >= 'A' && location[1] <= 8) || location[1] >= 1)
```

Which is clearly not what you intended.

You can put as many expressions in the condition as you want, but you must remember the precedence rules; I suggest always using extra parentheses for clarity.

As Jeremiah has pointed out in the comments, the condition still wouldn't be doing what you wanted -- you are asking if something is in a given range by checking if it's *either* less than the upper bound or greater than the lower bound (this covers all input), when you intended to check whether the input was *both* larger than the lower bound and smaller than the upper:

```
if (location[0] <= 'H' && location[0] >= 'A' && location[1] <= 8 && location[1] >= 1)
```

In this case, since the operators are all `&&`, no extra parentheses are needed, though you can add them for extra clarity.

Comment: And the `||` operators need to be `&&` anyway; currently, the test will always pass.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, but its still not working. Any location outside the bounds still returns true

Comment: @bluetickk, because assume `location[0]` is `'L'`, this is `>` than 'A' so this evaluates to `true`. You need `&&`.

Comment: @jeremiah I switched them but now {A, 1} returns false

Comment: @bluetickk, I have the impression that I know what your problem is. Try : `if((location[0] <= 'H' && location[0] >= 'A') && (location[1] <= '8' && location[1] >= '1'))`

Answer (score 1):

You need `&&`s not `||`s. For example: `'Z' >= 'A' || 'Z' <= 'H'` is true.

```
if(location[0] <= 'H' && location[0] >= 'A' && location[1] <= 8 && location[1] >= 1)
```

While not necessary in this case, you should group your logic together with parenthesis (and if they were `||`s you would have to for it to work as expected):

```
if((location[0] <= 'H' && location[0] >= 'A') && (location[1] <= 8 && location[1] >= 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add parenthesis to group the conditions:

```
if( (location[0] <= 'H' || location[0] >= 'A') && (location[1] <= 8 || location[1] >= 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If location[0] was equal to 'J' (definitely NOT between 'A' and 'H'), your if-clause would be TRUE because even though location[0] <= 'H' is FALSE, location[0] >= 'A' is TRUE and you are using || (OR).  The problem is that you are using || (OR) instead of && (AND).  You need to use all && (AND) in the if-clause.

Comment: if((location[0] <= 'H' && location[0] >= 'A') && (location[1] <= 8 && location[1] >= 1)) - {A,1} returns false?

Comment: if((location[0] <= 'H' && location[0] >= 'A') && (location[1] <= 8 && location[1] >= 1)) - {A,1} would return true because each individual clause is true.

Answer (score 0):

`&&` has higher precedence than `||`. So, you may want to write it as

```
if((location[0] <= 'H' || location[0] >= 'A') && (location[1] <= 8 || location[1] >= 1))
```

If you already tried this, please tell what error you got

Answer (score -1):

<s>As you can see in [this operator precedence table](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/language/operator_precedence), `&&` is #13. It's higher up than `||`, which is #14.</s>

---

**Therefore:**

```
if(location[0] <= 'H' || location[0] >= 'A' 
&& location[1] <= 8 || location[1] >= 1)
```

**Is equivalent to:**

```
if(location[0] <= 'H' || (location[0] >= 'A' 
&& location[1] <= 8) || location[1] >= 1)
```

---

**You want:**

```
if((location[0] <= 'H' || location[0] >= 'A') &&
  (location[1] <= 8 || location[1] >= 1))
```

**Or even better:**

```
if(((location[0] <= 'H') || (location[0] >= 'A')) &&
  ((location[1] <= 8) || (location[1] >= 1)))
```

---

I always put brackets around everything except when `*/` and `+-` are concerned. Even if you memorize the table, you shouldn't assume others do.

It helps code readability and helps prevent bugs... even compiler bugs! Triple bonus. :)

EDIT: Ah, you want ALL of them to be true. Just use *all* `&&`s, then! This works:

```
if(((location[0] <= 'H') && (location[0] >= 'A')) &&
  ((location[1] <= 8) && (location[1] >= 1)))
```

Comment: It's still wrong. if `location[0]` is 'L' this will evaluate to `true`